# How does the `--defsym` linker flag work to pass values to source code?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, casting, linker

In an [LJ post](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/add-auto-incrementing-build-number-your-build-process), the `--defsym` flag was used for passing the build date into the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char __BUILD_DATE;

void main(void) {
    printf("Build date: %u\n", (unsigned long) &__BUILD_DATE);
}
```

by linking with the following flags:

```
gcc example.c -Xlinker --defsym -Xlinker __BUILD_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
```

According to the [ld manual](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html),

> `--defsym symbol=expression` Create a global symbol in the output file, containing the absolute address given by expression.

I am trying to understand the following:

1. How is the 9-character string for the build date (`YYYYmmdd`+`\0`) stored in memory?
2. If `--defsym` creates a symbol containing an address, why `__BUILD_DATE` is defined as a char and not as a pointer or as an integral type?
3. Why `__BUILD_DATE` is defined as `char` and not `unsigned long` if it is eventually casted to `unsigned long`?

Comment: That looks like 3 questions to me. Not one. Maybe you want to post 3 individual questions..?

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think it's 3 small parts of one questions about the usage of `--defsym`. It makes no sense to me to split the question.

Comment: "Why __BUILD_DATE is defined as char and not unsigned long if it is eventually casted to unsigned long?" Is definitely a standalone question IMHO. As is "If --defsym creates a symbol containing an address, why __BUILD_DATE is defined as a char and not as a pointer or as an integral type?". But, that may just be me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linkers see globals as addresses (pointers to the "actual" global rather than the actual global -- even if the actual global doesn't exist at that address). `-Xlinker --defsym -Xlinker __BUILD_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)` sets the address `of __BUILD_DATE` not the value. When the `__BUILD_DATE` linker entity has an address but not a value, you can get the address by declaring the entity as anything and then taking the address of that.

In:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//extern long __BUILD_DATE[128];
//extern int __BUILD_DATE;
extern char __BUILD_DATE;

int main(void) 
{
    printf("Build date: %lu\n", (unsigned long)&__BUILD_DATE);
}
```

Any of the three declarations should work. Just don't try to use the value of that (pseudo) global. That would be like dereferencing an invalid pointer.

That should answer 2 and 3. To answer 1, `-Xlinker --defsym -Xlinker __BUILD_DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)` stores the number returned (stdout) by `$(date %Y%m%d)` as the address of `__BUILD_DATE`. It doesn't store a string.

Comment: so anything passed using `--defsym` can only be as large as `size_t`/`ptrdiff_t`?

Comment: @Sparkler There doesn't need to be much of a correlation between the linker's limits and the limits of C types, but practically you very likely won't be able to store addresses larger than your SIZE_MAX.

Comment: Interestingly, the above's only working for me with clang. I can't quite get it to work if I use gcc for linking (with whatever `-fuse-ld` option or without it). The debugger always shows the stored timestamp if I do `p (unsigned long)&__BUILD_DATE` but the program's printing the stored value offset by `0xffffaaaaaaaac000` but only if my system's address layout randomization's off. (Otherwise it's random). I don't have an explanation for this.